# Customized Rich Text Editor in Sitecore to generate BBCode tags instead of HTML

Tags: sitecore, bbcode, rich-text-editor

I am  currently creating a mobile site using Sitecore, where I cannot use HTML as markup instead need to use BML as markup language for mobile. Please let me know the following in this regard:

1. We have a field called `Description` and its of type `RICH TEXT`. Here we cannot use the normal Rich Text Editor given by the Sitecore as it generates HTML. So can anyone tell me if I can create a customized RICH TEXT Editor with a button Say "Mobile Bold" and which should generate tags for mobile instead of normal HTML `<b></b>` tags .
2. As you all know we can change the RICH TEXT Editor from Default to FULL by setting the source attribute of the field to `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full`. So in the similar way can I create one more item in the Core DB as `/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/MobileRichTextFull` and include customized buttons to it so as to generate BML tags as described above. If this is possible let me know what are all the settings need to be done and steps to be followed for the same.

Answer (score 0):

do you want the users to edit BML directly, or are you able to transform HTML to BML?

For the latter, you'd better solve this in the presentation layer/pipeline. 
HTML Agility Pack will be your friend when going for this last solution.

Otherwise, look at Teleriks resources about the editor.